# export PATH only once per login in zsh

Tags: zsh, environment-variables, session, profile

I need to alter my `PATH` variable so I put `export PATH=$PATH:somedir` in my `$HOME/.profile` which is sourced by my `$HOME/.zshrc`.

This works, yet whenever I open a new terminal (`urxvt` in `X11`), `.zshrc` and thus `.profile` is read, adding the `:somedir` to the `PATH`  again.

In my day to day computer use, the terminal windows come and go a lot, so after three hours of usage the `PATH` variable contains hundreds of clones of the `:somedir` appendix.

How do I fix this? Is there a config file which is read by `zsh` only on login?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [zsh man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/zsh1.html):

> [...] Commands  are then read from `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv`.  If the shell is a login shell, commands are read from `/etc/zprofile`  and  then  `$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile`. Then,  if  the  shell  is  interactive,  commands are read from `/etc/zshrc` and then `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`.  Finally, if the shell is a  login     shell, `/etc/zlogin` and `$ZDOTDIR/.zlogin` are read.

You should do your `PATH` changes in `.zprofile` (that could source `.profile` if you want), not in `.zshrc`.

Comment: Much better than my own answer.  Thank you.